# Funtion "provjera2()" only print "True"

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript Quiz for school. My problem is that my function which I will provide only prints "True". In HTML I have 4 options for answer and only one is correct.

```js
function provjera2(){
    var tocno2 = document.getElementById("2p3").textContent;
    if(document.getElementById("2p3").textContent == tocno2){
        alert("True!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it always true, you are compering value to itself...

Comment: Why should it do something else? The content of `tocno2` is the same as `document.getElementById("2p3").textContent`

Comment: and just a Hint: use better the === than the == to compare 2 things ;)